# Почему не применяется стиль для UserControl?

Tags: wpf, style, usercontrol

Имеется `UserControl`, у него заданы `Width`, `Height` и `Backgroung`.
При использовании этого контрола не получается переопределить эти значения через стиль, почему?

**Пользовательский контрол:**

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="ExperimentsWpf.UserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Width="100"
    Height="100"
    d:DesignHeight="450"
    d:DesignWidth="800"
    Background="Red"
    mc:Ignorable="d" />
```

**Использование:**

```
<Window
    x:Class="ExperimentsWpf.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ExperimentsWpf">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="StyleUserControl1" TargetType="{x:Type local:UserControl1}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="10" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="10" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <local:UserControl1 Style="{StaticResource StyleUserControl1}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос связан с порядком (приоритетом) выбора значения свойства зависимости.

Дело в том, что *явная установка* значения свойства зависимости (в разметке xaml или в "застраничном" коде – не важно) имеет наивысший приоритет.

Именно это и наблюдается в вашем коде: `Background="Red"` – это свойство установлено явно и переопределить его можно только явно: `<local:UserControl1 Background="Green"/>`, но это, как вы понимаете, неправильный негибкий путь.

Правильно же определить стиль по умолчанию и устанавливать значения свойств по умолчанию в нем. Стиль можно как вынести в ресурсы, так и разместить прямо в разметке контрола, например:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="ExperimentsWpf.UserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    d:DesignHeight="450"
    d:DesignWidth="800"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <UserControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="UserControl">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Style>
</UserControl>
```

После этого установка свойств через кастомный стиль, понятно, работает как ожидается.

Документация: [Dependency Property Value Precedence](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence)